using libraries that reqiuers interactoin with AppCompatActivity in Godot Android Plugin
I want to use cafebazaar poolaki library for implementing Cafe Bazaar in app billing inside godot android exported games. however from my undrestanding GodotPlugin class is inherited from FragmentActivity() which don't support functionalities from AppCompatActivity() which poolaki requires. and I can't have an instance of AppCompatActivity() inside myplugin(it causes FATAL error and crash). can anyone help me with the situatio?
btw im not android developer :)
this is my Bazar class:
package org.godotengine.plugin.android.template

import android.app.Activity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.os.PersistableBundle
import android.util.Log
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import ir.cafebazaar.poolakey.Connection
import ir.cafebazaar.poolakey.Payment
import ir.cafebazaar.poolakey.config.PaymentConfiguration
import ir.cafebazaar.poolakey.config.SecurityCheck
import ir.cafebazaar.poolakey.request.PurchaseRequest


class Bazar() : AppCompatActivity() {

    private val paymentConfiguration = PaymentConfiguration(
        localSecurityCheck = SecurityCheck.Enable(rsaPublicKey = "KEY")
    )

    private val payment by lazy(LazyThreadSafetyMode.NONE) {
        Payment(context = this, config = paymentConfiguration)
    }

    private lateinit var paymentConnection: Connection

//    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
//        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
//        connect()
//    }
    fun connect() {
        paymentConnection = payment.connect {
            connectionSucceed {
//                Toast.makeText(activity, "Connected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                Log.i("godot", "connection succeed!")
            }
            connectionFailed {
//                Toast.makeText(activity, "Connection failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                Log.i("godot", "connection failed!")
            }
            disconnected {
//                Toast.makeText(activity, "Disconnected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                Log.i("godot", "disconnected")
            }
        }
    }

    private val purchaseRequest = PurchaseRequest(
        productId = "PRODUCT_ID",
        payload = "PAYLOAD"
    )

    fun startPayment() {
        Log.i("godot", "payment started")
        payment.purchaseProduct(registry = activityResultRegistry, request = purchaseRequest) {
            purchaseFlowBegan {
//                Toast.makeText(activity, "Purchase flow began", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                Log.i("godot", "purchase flow began")

            }
            failedToBeginFlow { throwable ->
//                Toast.makeText(
//                    activity,
//                    "Failed to begin purchase flow: ${throwable.message}",
//                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG
//                ).show()
                Log.e("godot", "startPayment: ${throwable.message}")
            }
            purchaseSucceed { purchaseEntity ->
//                Toast.makeText(
//                    activity,
//                    "Purchase succeeded: ${purchaseEntity.purchaseToken}",
//                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG
//                ).show()
                Log.i("godot", "purchase succeeded")

            }
            purchaseCanceled {
//                Toast.makeText(activity, "Purchase canceled", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }
            purchaseFailed { throwable ->
//                Toast.makeText(activity, "Purchase failed: ${throwable.message}", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
//                    .show()
                Log.e("godot", "startPayment(purchaseFailed): ${throwable.message}")

            }
        }
    }
}

and this is my plugin class:

package org.godotengine.plugin.android.template

import android.util.Log
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.activity.result.ActivityResultRegistryOwner
import org.godotengine.godot.Godot
import org.godotengine.godot.plugin.GodotPlugin
import org.godotengine.godot.plugin.UsedByGodot


class GodotAndroidPlugin(godot: Godot) : GodotPlugin(godot){
    private val context = godot.getAndroidContext()

    private var bazar: Bazar? = null

    override fun getPluginName() = BuildConfig.GODOT_PLUGIN_NAME

    @UsedByGodot
    fun initiatePayment() {
        runOnUiThread {
            bazar = Bazar().apply { connect() }
        }
    }

    @UsedByGodot
    fun helloWorld() {
        runOnUiThread {
            Toast.makeText(activity, "Hello World", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            Log.v(pluginName, "Hello World")
        }
    }

    override fun onMainDestroy() {
        // bazar?.disconnectPayment()
        super.onMainDestroy()
    }
}

